# C Wire doesn’t work

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Trying to swap an old Honeywell thermostat for new with Wi-Fi. Old thermostat doesn’t need C wire, but I have an unused blue wire in the wall. I installed the new thermostat correctly with the C wire, went down to my furnace and securely connected the C wire into the C terminal there (there’s another wire in the terminal as well, I’ve double checked their connections), but still get no power to the thermostat. Furnace is a mid-00s electric Frigidaire, pretty simple setup. I’ve swapped thermostats before but have yet to run into this problem, any help appreciated!

Upstairs (thermostat I have tried to replace):
[image]

Downstairs (no changes other than connecting C wire to C terminal):
[image]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: Start by verifying you have voltage between C-wire post and hot side at the furnace connection block.  Then verify same up at  the thermostat location.   Are there any other thermostats in the house (in which case there might be multiple 'blue wires'  down by the furnace)?

Comment: I do have another furnace downstairs on a separate circuit breaker with it’s own thermostat, I have not replaced that thermostat yet. I did hook it’s C wire up at furnace, but have not yet done so at the thermostat itself. They appear to be wired separately. I have pictures of the wiring of both furnaces that I will attempt to post.

Comment: Yes, can you measure 24V between R and C at the upstairs furnace? Also, does the air conditioning upstairs work? Or is that thing connected only to Y and C at the upstairs furnace something else instead of an air conditioner?

Comment: I don’t have my multimeter right now but I can probably get another later today. The AC works fine, all of it works.